# Can the JVM provide snapshot persistence?

Tags: java, jvm

Is it possible to dump an image of a running JVM and later restore the previous state by loading the image into the JVM?  I'm fairly certain the answer is negative, but would love to be wrong.

With all the dynamic languages available for the JVM comes an increase in interactivity, being able to save a coding session would help save time manually restoring the VM to a previous session.

Comment: This would be amazingly useful in grid computing where one might want to move his process to lightly loaded machine in the grid. Creating a recoverable snapshot would be a great win.
Guys please give it a thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a [JSR 323 proposed for this](http://tech.puredanger.com/2008/01/09/strong-mobility-for-java/) a while back but it was [rejected](http://tech.puredanger.com/2008/01/24/jcp-votes-down-jsr-323/).  You can find some links in those articles about the research behind this and what it would take.  It was mostly rejected as an idea that was too immature.

I have heard of at least one startup (unfortunately don't recall the name) that was working on a virtualization technology over a hypervisor (probably Xen) that was getting pretty close to being able to move JVMs, including even things like file system refs and socket endpoints.  Because they were at the hypervisor level, they had access to all of that stuff.  By hooking that and the JVM, they had most of the pieces.  I think they might have gone under though.

The closest thing you can get today is [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org), which allows you to cluster a portion of your JVM heap, storing it in a server array, which can be made persistent.  On JVM startup, you connect to the cluster and can continue using whatever portions of your heap are specified as clustered.  The actual objects are faulted in on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible at present. In general, pausing and restarting a memory image of a process in a different context is incredibly hard to achieve: what are you going to do with open OS resources? Transfers to machines with different instruction sets? database connections?

Also images of the running JVM are probably quite large - maybe much larger than the subset of the state you are actually interested in. So it's not a good idea from a performance perspective.

A much better strategy is to have **code that persists and recreates the application state**: this is relatively feasible with most JVM dynamic languages. I do so similar stuff in Clojure, where you have an interactive environment (REPL) and it is quite possible to create and run a sequence of operations that rebuild the application state that you want in another JVM.

Comment: We used to do this with Smalltalk vm/images ... incredibly useful for debugging client issues ... freeze the image, bring it back to basecamp and step through the code from the line we stopped at client site. In many cases we didn't care about all those connections to external filesystems, databases, sockets ... we just needed to navigate various internal data structures as they existed at the client site.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible in any of the JVMs I know. It would not be very difficult to implement something like this in the JVM if programs run disconnected from their environments. However, many programs have hooks into their environment (think file handles, database connections) which would make implementing something like this very hairy.

Answer (score 1):

As of early 2023, there's some progress in this space and it seems a lot of things can at least be tried, even if without claims for their production readiness.

One such feature is called [CRaC](https://openjdk.org/projects/crac/). You can check their [docs](https://github.com/CRaC/docs) or even get an [OpenJDK build](https://github.com/CRaC/openjdk-builds/releases) that includes the feature. The project has its [own repo](https://github.com/openjdk/crac) under OpenJDK and looks quite promising.

Another vendors/products to check:
[Azul ReadyNow!](https://www.azul.com/products/components/readynow/)
[OpenJ9 InstantOn](https://openliberty.io/blog/2022/09/29/instant-on-beta.html)

What's also really exciting, is [AWS Lambda SnapStart](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/aws-lambda-snapstart-java-functions/). It doesn't give you full snapshoting capabilities, and is intrinsically vendor-specific, but it's what a ton of Java engineering who use AWS Lambda were waiting for so long.