# How can I halt JVM, store the JVM state on HDD, and restart whenever required

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to halt running JVM and store its state in persistant storage like HDD. 
Then i should be able to restart the JVM from the point where I had stopped.
I would like to have windows hibernate kind a functionality for JVM.

Comment: Alternatively: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611134/can-the-jvm-provide-snapshot-persistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with VM hibernation. You can have a VM run an OS which is stopped, saved, reloaded and restarted.  The JVM doesn't support this directly.

An alternative is to persist the data off-heap which allows you to stop the start of the JVM and restart it very quickly (not zero but sub-second even for large data sets)

Comment: I think [apache Sandbox](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-javaflow/index.html) might help me.
Also I found [link](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~eddy.truyen/BRAKES/brakes.html) which will help too

Comment: two more interesting links
[http://www.research-projects.uzh.ch](http://www.research-projects.uzh.ch/p1753.htm)

[http://arnetminer.org/..](http://arnetminer.org/publication/m-javampi-a-java-mpi-binding-with-process-migration-support-82919.html)