# modify a simulation program written in java-maven project into a restartable one

Tags: java, performance

I have a simulation program coded in java - maven, I'm running it on a cluster machine, but there's a wall-time limit. So ideally I'd like to modify the code to make it restartable (i.e. it is able to stop at one point and restart from the point), I have never done this before, can someone give me some hint what process I should follow, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want to modify the code, run it in a virtual machine and suspend/resume the VM. :D

Comment: This is a too broad topic. It basically depends on some kind of external storage. [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611134/can-the-jvm-provide-snapshot-persistence)

Comment: I recommend looking into the concept of *checkpointing*.

Comment: @Luke suspending VM does it mean the job is killed or just paused on the cluster machine? Sorry, I just don't have any knowledge about this.

Comment: It's paused. But it's not that simple. Depending on the resources your simulation requires, it might not function properly after it resumes. Best let your program react to some shutdown signal.

Comment: @Luke, as far as I understood, on a cluster machine, even the job is paused, the cpu-time still continues till it passes the wall-time allowance?

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf I think I am late but I provided an extension with some source example. Please have a look at it. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing comes to my mind is to serialize your object model. What i mean is, when you start your simulation, first of all, it looks for a special file, which holds serialized form of your entire object tree. If there is any, it de-serializes it, and goes on from there. If not starts as usual, and before stopping, it again serializes its state, writing into that special file and then quits.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It definitely does. As an extension, he can create a shutdown hook and use that thread to serialize the state of application. Would it be a good idea?

Comment: Sounds like a good enhancement. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Alp I vaguely get what you mean, so I guess my updated question is: how to find this serialized state as you mentioned? is it stored in a file under some specific directory? If not, any ways I can obtain it?

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf What I did was to create a `Lifecycle` interface and its base implementation. Maybe you can salvage something from that so that you can start serializing your objects into a file...

Comment: @GarryLittlewolf Please look for serialization of Java Objects. It is quite straight forward, specially if you do NOT need the serialized form in other formats, like XML, JSON, GSON etc. I think you really do not need it in XML or so on. So stick to the default binary form. Let Java do the work for you. All you need to know is your "STATE" (or current object model) is written into the disk as a file and read. That's all. :)

Comment: @Alp You added that comment just when I finished writing mine. I was about to say your point. Instead of just dumping whole states into a file, you can use a more appropriate format like JSON and XML for consistency's sake. And please look at the comment I made directed to the OP

Comment: @Jay, converting into JSON or other formats may be required, ONLY if human intervention/comprehension is needed in serialized form of data/state. Otherwise, it just adds extra complexity.

Comment: @Alp yea 100% correct. I have an idea about this. Can we [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128772/modify-a-simulation-program-written-in-java-maven-project-into-a-restartable-one)?

Comment: Hi @Alp . I have provided an extension to your answer in this thread. Can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can register a shutdown hook to be run when the JVM is about to quit, either exiting normally by "falling-off" the main method or by some external signal like `^C` or OS reboot event.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // Save program state for later
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so [@Alp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014959/alp) already has provided a good answer and I am answering after this answer has been accepted.

> First thing comes to my mind is to serialize your object model. What i
>   mean is, when you start your simulation, first of all, it looks for a
>   special file, which holds serialized form of your entire object tree.
>   If there is any, it de-serializes it, and goes on from there. If not
>   starts as usual, and before stopping, it again serializes its state,
>   writing into that special file and then quits.

As an extension, I would like to add some code implementations.

You can design a [`Lifecycle` interface](https://github.com/Corticera/AppServer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/corticerasf/corticera/lifecycle/Lifecycle.java) and implement it in your components so that they can have a valid `init() -> start() -> stop() -> destroy()` life. You can have your components to initialize or load data from an existing dump in `init()` and serialize the states in `stop()` functions.

To add some simplicity, you can have a base implementation of `Lifecycle` interface that you can extend to your components.

---

### Additional References:

- [The Lifecycle package from my project](https://github.com/Corticera/AppServer/tree/master/src/main/java/org/corticerasf/corticera/lifecycle).

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for the enhancement :)

Comment: @Alp thanks :) I would like and appreciate if you could [contribute](https://github.com/Corticera/AppServer) to my project. :D